Cassandra write task failure not retried after upgraded to apache spark 3.4.x
We have been using spark with Cassandra. We upgraded from spark 3.2 to spark 3.4. But after the upgrade, we noticed an annoying issue. Occasional write timeout failure in one writing task become fatal failures. Read failure are still handled well with retry. But write failures are no longer retried.
We use Cassandra, which can handle repeated writing of same data. We wish there is a mechanism to tell spark to retry write tasks.
We read the source code, and found write retry was intentionally removed.

Can you create an issue on the repo? https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
